# JQuery Mobile Content Padding Top is Incorrect on first load

Tags: jquery-mobile

i'm using jquery 1.1.0 and i have a custom header here

i've set the css of this header to be a height of 200px; (i hardcoded it for testing, if i place items in there to make it dynamically get to 200 px, it's the same thing)

the problem is when i transition to another page

$.mobile.changePage("#SurveyCreateView", "none", false, false);

the content on the second page basically ignores the height of the custom header i have. (so the content starts all the way at the top) if i resize the window or if i do a back, and navigate to the second view again, then everything is okay.

anybody have any idea how to fix this?